# External hard drive keeps crashing ubuntu-20.10-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi

Tags: server, usb, external-hdd

This freshly reinstalled raspberry pi keeps rebooting on it's own when the external HDD is connected.. An so I keep losing my ssh connection.

I had formatted and reformatted the disk a lot before, event made it as a ubuntu bootable device, not to sure what it could have caused and how I could set it back to 0 now.. (because other drives are working and I can mount them)

`lsblk`, `gparted` and `fdisk` can't see it, However it is visible on `lsusb` when I spam it with whith commands before the reboot

This is what I get when running '`journalctl`' :

```
Nov 26 19:05:09 ubuntu kernel: usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Nov 26 19:05:09 ubuntu kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=0237, bcdDevice= 5.10
Nov 26 19:05:09 ubuntu kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov 26 19:05:09 ubuntu kernel: usb 1-1.2: Product: Portable USB 3.0 Drive
Nov 26 19:05:09 ubuntu kernel: usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Verbatim
Nov 26 19:05:09 ubuntu kernel: usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 1707190400100764
Nov 26 19:05:09 ubuntu kernel: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Nov 26 19:05:09 ubuntu kernel: scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
Nov 26 19:05:09 ubuntu kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Nov 26 19:05:09 ubuntu kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Nov 26 19:05:12 ubuntu kernel: scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  MQ01ABF050       AM00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Nov 26 19:05:12 ubuntu kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Nov 26 19:05:12 ubuntu kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773164 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
Nov 26 19:05:12 ubuntu kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Nov 26 19:05:12 ubuntu kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Nov 26 19:05:12 ubuntu kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Nov 26 19:05:14 ubuntu kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=1s
Nov 26 19:05:14 ubuntu kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
Nov 26 19:05:14 ubuntu kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - recommend rewrite the data
Nov 26 19:05:14 ubuntu kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 04 00
Nov 26 19:05:14 ubuntu kernel: blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sda, sector 4 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys>
Nov 26 19:05:14 ubuntu kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 1, async page read
Nov 26 19:05:15 ubuntu kernel:  sda: sda1
Nov 26 19:05:16 ubuntu multipath[2032]: sda: can't store path info
Nov 26 19:05:30 ubuntu kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Nov 26 19:05:31 ubuntu multipathd[1523]: uevent trigger error
-- Reboot --
```

Comment: Your system does see the disk: `/dev/sda`, and the partition: `/dev/sda1`. But, "`Unrecovered read error - recommend rewrite the data`" is a disk-specific message. Check the manufacturer's website for more info. Ensure that neither `/dev/sda` nor `/dev/sda1` is mounted. `mount | grep /dev/sda` to check.

Comment: When I would connect a usb I could mount it and unmount it easily on sda1.  I tried with another hard drive and now both hard drives are causing problems, even on my Windows machine... I reinstalled Ubuntu, but left the usb plugged in and now I can't even ssh back in.. lol. Where did you learn about this stuff? where could I become knowledgeable in this dark magic art?